# IntelliJ idea cannot open “File->open url ”

Tags: intellij-idea

my idea cannot open menu bar ; how can I fix it?

The log is :

```
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.7  Build #IU-141.3058.30 
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - JDK: 1.8.0_181 
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - OS: Mac OS X 
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - Last Action:  
2018-11-29 17:26:31,193 [  37873]  ERROR - Templates.impl.DefaultTemplate - Entry fileTemplates//j2ee/valueResourceFile.xml.html not found in /Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2014.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/resources_en.jar 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//j2ee/valueResourceFile.xml.html not found in /Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%2014.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/resources_en.jar
    at com.intellij.util.io.URLUtil.openJarStream(URLUtil.java:98)
    at com.intellij.util.io.URLUtil.openStream(URLUtil.java:59)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.impl.UrlUtil.loadText(UrlUtil.java:45)
```

Comment: I installed 2 versions of  the intelij idea

Comment: Seems you are running pretty old IDE version. Have you tried 2018?

Comment: yes , the older IDE version is 14. It's work when i update to 2018.thanks